# Occasional Bad Data Error while decrypting the string : System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException

Tags: .net, asp.net, cryptography, encryption, encryption-symmetric

In my ASP.NET WebForms App ***(The app is running on windows server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5 and Runtime v4.0 Integrated Mode App Pool if it matters)***, I am encrypting data, putting it on the QueryString and decrypting data using `System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm` class. But I am occasionally having some problems with decrypting the data I am getting the following exception;

> Bad Data.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
>   Bad Data.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [CryptographicException: Bad Data. ]
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr) +33
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptData(SafeKeyHandle
>   hKey, Byte[] data, Int32 ib, Int32 cb,
>   Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32
>   outputOffset, PaddingMode PaddingMode,
>   Boolean fDone) +0
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoAPITransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[]
>   inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32
>   inputCount) +313
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
>   +33    Cryptography35.SymmetricEncryptionUtility.DecryptData(Byte[]
>   data, String keyFile) in
>   E:\Documents\@Library\Cryptography35\Cryptography35\SymmetricEncryptionUtility.cs:124
>   Cryptography35.SymmetricQueryString.SymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString..ctor(String
>   encryptedData, String keyfilename,
>   String algorithmname) in
>   E:\Documents\@Library\Cryptography35\Cryptography35\SymmetricQueryString\SymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString.cs:67
>   WebForms.Web.Views.purchase_a.GetSymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString()
>   in
>   E:\Documents\WebForms.Web\Views\purchase-a.aspx.cs:35
>   WebForms.Web.Views.purchase_a.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   E:\Documents\WebForms.Web\Views\purchase-a.aspx.cs:56
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>   +14    System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +35
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +91
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +74    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
>       Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

As I indicated, I am getting this error on occasion, not every time I run that. I don't know where I am doing it wrong *(on the encryption stage or decryption stage)* Here is the code I used for that;

```
private SymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString GetSymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString() {

    #region _decrypting the value

    string KeyFileName;
    string AlgorithmName = "DES";

    Cryptography35.SymmetricEncryptionUtility.AlgorithmName = AlgorithmName;
    KeyFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/@config/") + "\\symmetric_key.config";

    #endregion

    #region _reading and assigning the value

    if (Request.QueryString["q"] == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("QueryString value is null on search result page");

    SymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString QueryString = new SymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString(Request.QueryString["q"], KeyFileName, AlgorithmName);

    #endregion

    return QueryString;
}
```

`SymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString` Class

```
public class SymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString : System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary {

        public string KeyFileName { get; set; }
        public string AlgorithmName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use this for encrypte the value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="keyfilename"></param>
        /// <param name="algorithmname"></param>
        public SymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString(string keyfilename, string algorithmname) {

            KeyFileName = keyfilename;
            AlgorithmName = algorithmname;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use this for decrypte the value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="encryptedData"></param>
        /// <param name="keyfilename"></param>
        /// <param name="algorithmname"></param>
        public SymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString(string encryptedData, string keyfilename, string algorithmname) {

            #region _initials

            KeyFileName = keyfilename;
            AlgorithmName = algorithmname;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(AlgorithmName)){
                SymmetricEncryptionUtility.AlgorithmName = AlgorithmName;
            }
            else{
                SymmetricEncryptionUtility.AlgorithmName = "DES";
            }

            SymmetricEncryptionUtility.ProtectKey = false;

            // Check for encryption key
            if (!File.Exists(KeyFileName)){
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Keyfilename for  SymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString is not found on '" + KeyFileName + "'!");
            }

            #endregion

            //Arrange the data
            //In order not to get following exception
            //Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.
            //byte[] RawData = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData);
            encryptedData = encryptedData.Replace(" ", "+");
            int mod4 = encryptedData.Length % 4;
            if (mod4 > 0)
                encryptedData += new string('=', 4 - mod4);

            // Decrypt data passed in
            byte[] RawData = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData);
            string DecryptedVal = SymmetricEncryptionUtility.DecryptData(RawData, KeyFileName);
            string StringData = DecryptedVal;

            // Split the data and add the contents
            int Index;
            string[] SplittedData = StringData.Split(new char[] { '&' });
            foreach (string SingleData in SplittedData) {

                Index = SingleData.IndexOf('=');
                base.Add(
                    HttpUtility.UrlDecode(SingleData.Substring(0, Index)),
                    HttpUtility.UrlDecode(SingleData.Substring(Index + 1))
                );

            }
        }

        public override string ToString() {

            #region _initials

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(AlgorithmName)) {
                SymmetricEncryptionUtility.AlgorithmName = AlgorithmName;
            } else {
                SymmetricEncryptionUtility.AlgorithmName = "DES";
            }

            SymmetricEncryptionUtility.ProtectKey = false;

            // Check for encryption key
            if (!File.Exists(KeyFileName)) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Keyfilename for AsymmetriclyEncryptedQueryString is not found on '" + KeyFileName + "'!");
            }

            #endregion

            #region _prepare for querystring

            // Go through the contents and build a 
            // typical query string
            StringBuilder Content = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string key in base.Keys) {

                Content.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key));
                Content.Append("=");
                Content.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base[key]));
                Content.Append("&");

            }

            // Remove the last '&'
            Content.Remove(Content.Length - 1, 1);


            #endregion

            #region _encrypt the contents

            // Now encrypt the contents
            byte[] data = SymmetricEncryptionUtility.EncryptData(Content.ToString(), KeyFileName);
            string EncryptedVal = Convert.ToBase64String(data);

            #endregion

            return EncryptedVal;

        }

    }
```

`SymmetricEncryptionUtility` Class

```
public static class SymmetricEncryptionUtility {

    private static bool _ProtectKey;
    private static string _AlgorithmName;

    // Shhh!!! Don't tell anybody!
    private const string MyKey = "m$%&kljasldk$%/65asjdl";

    public static string AlgorithmName {

        get { return _AlgorithmName; }
        set { _AlgorithmName = value; }
    }

    public static bool ProtectKey {

        get { return _ProtectKey; }
        set { _ProtectKey = value; }
    }

    public static void GenerateKey(string targetFile) {

        // Create the algorithm
        SymmetricAlgorithm Algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(AlgorithmName);
        Algorithm.GenerateKey();

        // No get the key
        byte[] Key = Algorithm.Key;

        if (ProtectKey)
        {
            // Use DPAPI to encrypt key
            Key = ProtectedData.Protect(
                Key, null, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
        }

        // Store the key in a file called key.config
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(Key, 0, Key.Length);
        }
    }

    public static void ReadKey(SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, string keyFile)
    {
        byte[] Key;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(keyFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            Key = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(Key, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        }

        if (ProtectKey)
            algorithm.Key = ProtectedData.Unprotect(Key, null, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
        else
            algorithm.Key = Key;
    }

    public static byte[] EncryptData(string data, string keyFile)
    {
        // Convert string data to byte array
        byte[] ClearData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        // Now Create the algorithm
        SymmetricAlgorithm Algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(AlgorithmName);
        ReadKey(Algorithm, keyFile);

        // Encrypt information
        MemoryStream Target = new MemoryStream();

        // Append IV
        Algorithm.GenerateIV();
        Target.Write(Algorithm.IV, 0, Algorithm.IV.Length);

        // Encrypt actual data
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(Target, Algorithm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(ClearData, 0, ClearData.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Output the bytes of the encrypted array to the textbox
        return Target.ToArray();
    }

    public static string DecryptData(byte[] data, string keyFile) {

        // Now create the algorithm
        SymmetricAlgorithm Algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(AlgorithmName);
        ReadKey(Algorithm, keyFile);

        // Decrypt information
        MemoryStream Target = new MemoryStream();

        // Read IV
        int ReadPos = 0;
        byte[] IV = new byte[Algorithm.IV.Length];
        Array.Copy(data, IV, IV.Length);
        Algorithm.IV = IV;
        ReadPos += Algorithm.IV.Length;

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(Target, Algorithm.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(data, ReadPos, data.Length - ReadPos);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Get the bytes from the memory stream and convert them to text
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Target.ToArray());
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**
I figured something else. On one of my pages I am doing the following thing;

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {

    string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower();
    if (url.StartsWith("http:"))
    {
        Response.Redirect(url.Replace("http://", "https://"), true);
    }
}
```

I figured that it causes the problem. (Remember that my encrypted data sits inside the Query String) when I try to reach that page from `http` and it redirects it to `https` and boom. it gives me that error. ok now I found the source of the error but it shouldn't be happening anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You have a bug lurking in your code...

You should never use any of the System.Text.Encoding classes for cipher text. You *will* experience intermittent errors.  You should use Base64 encoding and the System.Convert class methods.

1. To obtain an encrypted string from an encrypted byte[], you should use: `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] bytes)`
2. To obtain a a raw byte[] from a string to be encrypted, you should use: `Convert.FromBase64String(string data)`

For additional info, please refer to MS Security guru Shawn Farkas's post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/11/10/491431.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had a different root cause, for "Bad Data" error, and that was related to not having the "FlushFinalBlock" code. This obviously caused a problem as I never stored the fully encrypted value.
Now in the code example above that **is** included, but obvioulsy it is buried in the code. I hope this is not too off topic, but I did find this post from Google fairly quickly so I assume others might come here and make that same simple mistake as well.

It might also be worth mentioning that the @Dave Black answer does not appear to relate to the final code posted above... ? Have I read the code above correctly?
This might be a result of the changes over time - but this lead me slightly astray in trying to sort out what had gone wrong (I had stored my encrypted data correctly, just not all of it :-( )

Comment: @Orbonia, I was referring to the EncryptData/DecryptData methods in the OP's SymmetricEncryptionUtility class (which as of today 4/21/15 is still present in the original question).

Answer (score -1):

Set encryption and decryption mode to ECB.
As rossum say: "ECB is not secure, it leaks information" so if you need random access to your file Use CTR.

Comment: Don't do that.  ECB is not secure, it leaks information.  Use CTR or CBC instead.